# ODE: $y'=3e^{2(x+y)}-1$, $y(0)=7$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function

How can I solve the following differential equation? $$y'=3e^{2(x+y)}-1,\quad y(0)=7$$

I am failing to separate the variables, and I am not yet introduced to other solving-methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this problem does not make sense. What is $y$? what is $x$? Where is the "differential" part of the O**D**E? where is the "equation" part of the OD**E**?

Comment: Sorry, too fast. Edited.

Comment: Hint: $u=x+y$ is a good choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $u(x) = y(x) + x$ and note that

$$
\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}  + 1
$$

So that your equation becomes

$$
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} + 1 = 3e^{2(x+y)} ~~~\Rightarrow \frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x} = 3e^{2u}
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thanks. $y(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1}{e^{14}}-6x)-x$ should be correct.